# Handling different build scenarios in Eclipse for C project

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, build, build-process

I am working on embedded c project. Till now I was using batch files and cmd prompt to compile the source files. Now I am planning to use Eclipse IDE for editing the code and compilation. The folder structure is as follows (refer the image)

[image: Folder Structure]

Delivery folder remains same for all build scenarios since it contains the main module source files.

Test_Setup folder contains the test cases. Each TAxx had src and inc folder. In each TAxx_src folder, there is a .c file containing main function and and test functions. Currently using batch files for testing there is a batch file for each TAxx folder (in this case 4 batch files) which will compile the Delivery folder and the corresponding TAxx folder.

In eclipse I want to keep the same folder structure. But if I give build, eclipse will throw multiple "main" error. Hence I am unable to give build directly.

There is also a possibility of creating build configurations in eclipse. But since TAxx can be in 100s it will be difficult to create so many build configurations and maintain it.

1. How to effectively handle such a build scenario in eclipse. My task is to keep the folder structure same and while giving build, I must be able to select which TAxx folder I want to use for build.
2. Keeping the same folder structure, how can I compile Deliver folder and anyone TAxx folder?
3. Is there an option to create build configurations automatically?
4. After project is successful and all test cases are executed, the source code in moved to configuration management, but the eclipse project is not stored. Is there an option to export build configurations in a file so that it can be used when the project is again loaded in Eclipse?

Regards
Manoj

Comment: Do not add unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0):

Left click in the Project Explorer tab -> New -> C Project
[image: C Project creation]

A C projet will be created with 2 build configurations as default: Debug and Release.

Left click on your project just created.
Right click -> New -> Folder

This way add all your folders according to your Project structure.

Go to Properties -> C/C++ General -> Source location tab -> Add folder button

[image: Add source location]

Then select both folders available resulting in the following Project layout:

[image: Project layout]

Go to Properties -> C/C++ General -> Includes tab -> GNU C Language -> Add button

And finally add all your include paths resulting as follows:

[image: Add include paths]

To select which folders to be used for compilation, you rather have to select the folders that will be excluded from build. To do this right click on folder to exclude -> Resource Configurations -> Exclude From Build -> select the build configuration

[image]

This way building is acomplished as required in your bullet 1 and 2 questions.

Bullet 3 - It is possible through makefiles, although it's trickier then letting eclipse manage the build process.

Bullet 4 - Build configurations are already stored in the Project, so when you load it again will be there available again.

If you want to creat more build configurations right click in the Project, Build Configurations -> Manage -> New -> Copy settings from Existing Configuration

But in my opinion you don't need to create hundreds of build configurations in your case. Maybe just the 2 regular ones, Release and Debug are enough. Selection is made by choosing which TAxx folder will not be excluded from build.